# mysql - calculate difference between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, select, difference

I have a table which looks like below.

```
CREATE TABLE `table_growth` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `table_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rows` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=184 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Example of rows in the table:

```
+-----+---------------------+--------------------------+-------+
| id  | timestamp           | table_name               | rows  |
+-----+---------------------+--------------------------+-------+
| 110 | 2019-03-01 06:00:00 | attachments              |   640 |
| 111 | 2019-03-01 06:00:00 | contacts                 |     0 |
| 112 | 2019-03-01 06:00:00 | copy_menuitem_options    |  3038 |
| 113 | 2019-03-01 06:00:00 | copy_menuitem_suboptions |  9779 |
| 114 | 2019-03-01 06:00:00 | copy_menuitems           | 12118 |
| 115 | 2019-03-02 06:00:00 | attachments              |   638 |
| 116 | 2019-03-02 06:00:00 | contacts                 |     0 |
| 117 | 2019-03-02 06:00:00 | copy_menuitem_options    |  3039 |
| 118 | 2019-03-02 06:00:00 | copy_menuitem_suboptions |  9789 |
| 119 | 2019-03-02 06:00:00 | copy_menuitems           | 12128 |
+-----+---------------------+--------------------------+-------+
```

I want to calculate the `diff(rows)` between 2 days. like `date(timestamp)='2019-03-02' - date(timestamp)='2019-03-01'`

#### Expected results

```
table_name              | Rows Diff
------------------------------
attachments             | 2
contacts                | 0           
copy_menuitem_options   | 1
copy_menuitem_suboptions| 10 
copy_menuitems          | 10
```

I tried these queries, but somewhere its failing.

```
 SELECT x.table_name
     , (y.rows-x.rows)as diff
  FROM dbadmin.table_growth x
  JOIN dbadmin.table_growth y
    ON y.id = x.id
   AND DATE(y.timestamp) = '2019-03-02' 
 WHERE DATE(x.timestamp) = '2019-03-01';

select x.table_name, (y.rows - x.rows) as doff
from table_growth x join
table_growth y on y.id=x.id and DATE(y.timestamp) = '2019-03-02' 
WHERE DATE(x.timestamp) = '2019-03-01';
```

Comment: I believe you get an empty resultset because join on id columns will not work for your case since they are different. Attachments has 100 and 110 as id on different dates. What you need is an equivalent version of Oracle Analytical Functions in MySQL especially LEAD or LAG equivalent will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query is on the right track, but the join condition is partially off.  You should be asserting that the table names, not ids, match:

```
SELECT
    x.table_name,
    (x.rows - y.rows) AS diff
FROM table_growth x
INNER JOIN table_growth y
    ON x.table_name = y.table_name and
       DATE(y.timestamp) = '2019-03-02'
WHERE
    DATE(x.timestamp) = '2019-03-01';
```

Note: Your current output is slightly ambiguous, because it is not clear which `rows` value comes first in the difference, or if perhaps you want to report an absolute value.

Comment: if you remove the where condition it will give double number of rows!!!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh And your point is?  We're not planning to remove the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

this will work;

```
select distinct a.table_name,(a.rows-b.rows) diff from table_growth a,table_growth b 
where a.table_name=b.table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one row per date, then this might be the fastest approach:

```
SELECT g.table_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(g.timestamp) = '2019-03-02'
                THEN g.rows 
                WHEN DATE(g.timestamp) = '2019-03-01'
                THEN -g.rows
                ELSE 0
           END) as diff
FROM dbadmin.table_growth g
WHERE g.timestamp >= '2019-03-01' AND
      g.timestamp < '2019-03-03'
GROUP BY g.table_name;
```

In particular, this can make use of an index on `table_growth(timestamp, table_name, rows)`.